# Concerning Struct Constructor and Destructor behavior - C++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, destructor, multiple-inheritance

I don't understand why the output of this program is as follows. Why isn't there a compilation error? I thought when trying to construct B, the compiler would find no function called foo() and report an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    int a;
    A(int i=0) : a(i) { cout << "A" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "Bye A" << endl; }
    int foo() { return a; }
};
struct B{
    int b;
    B(int i=0) : b(i) { cout << "B" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "Bye B" << endl; }
    int bar() { return b; }
};
struct C : B, A {
    C(int i=0) : B(foo()), A(i) {}
};

int main() {
    cout << C(10).bar() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
B
A
0
Bye A
Bye B
```

In general, I would like to know when there is multiple inheritance, what is the order in which the parent structs are constructed and initialized? Can I expect a similar behavior in classes too?

Any explanation regarding the order of constructor and destructor calls is much appreciated.

**Note:** This is not homework. And, I have researched similar topics but nothing came up regarding this issue.

Comment: By the way, strictly saying there are no structs in C++, only classes. (`struct` declares a class too.) So, I expect them to behave in a same way.

Comment: I expect classes to behave exactly the same as structs. The main difference between the two is that members of structs are always public.

Comment: `foo` is a member of an accessible, unambiguous base of `C`, so what's the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854010/order-of-constructor-and-destructor-calling

Comment: @Mattia: "members of structs are always public" not true, just the default visibility is public for struct, but you can specify protected and/or private stuff in them, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The problem is calling `A::foo` before `A::A`. This returns an uninitialized `A::a`.

Comment: clang says `warning: base class 'A' is uninitialized when used here to access 'A::foo'`

Comment: Are you expecting the function `foo` to not exist until the `A` subobject has been constructed?

Comment: @MSalters: Sure, but you can pull that particular trigger in any number of ways: `X() : a(b), b(0) {}` etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Undefined behavior

You're invoking undefined behavior by calling `foo` before the object is fully initialized. Quote from 12.6.2 in the C++ standard :

> Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction.
>   Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly
>   or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializers* for base classes have completed, the result
>   of the operation is undefined. *[ Example:*

```
class A {
public:
  A(int);
};

class B : public A {
  int j;
public:
  int f();
  B() : A(f()),       // undefined: calls member function
                      // but base A not yet initialized
          j(f()) { }  // well-defined: bases are all initialized
};

class C {
public:
  C(int);
};

class D : public B, C {
  int i;
public:
  D() : C(f()),       // undefined: calls member function
                      // but base C not yet initialized
          i(f()) { }  // well-defined: bases are all initialized
};
```

> *— end example ]*

In other words, this would be ok according to the standard :

```
C(int i=0) : B(), A(i) {
    B::b = foo();
}
```

And this will print `10` instead of the `0` that you got (which could have been anything else, since that was undefined behavior).

### Initialization order

Setting aside this matter of undefined behavior, and to address your question, the order in which initialization happens is well-defined :

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in
>   the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes,
>   where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class *base-specifier-list*.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the *base-specifier-list*
>   (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> — Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> — Finally, the *compound-statement* of the constructor body is executed.
>
> *[ Note:* The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in
>   the reverse order of initialization. *— end note ]*

So, in your code, the initialization order is : `B` (`B::b`), `A` (`A::a`), `C` ().

As noted in the comments below though, changing this initialization order (by eg. using `struct C : A, B` instead of `struct C : B, A`) would not however get rid of the undefined behavior. Calling `A::foo` before the `B` part is initialized remains undefined, even if the `A` part is initialized.

Comment: However, the question is about a base class member function. It is basically the same but may be worth to mention whether the same would be UB for `struct C : A, B` (I think it would be legal then, first constructing A, then B)

Comment: @grek40 : the order of initialization doesn't matter in this case. If *any* part of the object is not yet initialized, calling *any* member function is undefined. Whether or not the `A` part is initialized by the time you call `A::foo` does not change anything, because the `B` part is not yet initialized at that point, so the object is not yet initialized.

Comment: But `foo` belongs to `A`, since it is a non-virtual member of `A`, so as soon as `A` and its potential base classes are constructed, `foo` would be ready to use, not only when `C` and its base classes are constructed. Calling `foo` without knowing its implementation details would still bear the risk of UB, since foo may in turn call virtual functions, but it's not UB by itself as far as I can read from your quote. The construction order of `A` and `B` is defined, right?

Comment: What I mean: "*However, if these operations are performed in a ctor-initializer [...] before all the mem-initializers for base classes have completed*" - who's mem-initializers are targeted here - the member function context or the concrete type context?

Comment: @grek40 : I've added the example from the standard that illustrates this. It explicitly states that calling `B::f` before the `C` part of `D` is initialized is undefined behavior (even though by that point the `B` part is initialized). While you're probably right that most compilers will treat this in the same way (the way you'd expect), the letter of the standard doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: Perfect, that `D` example nailed it.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker : No, over time for C's constructor, it becomes a B object then A object before becoming a C object, You can use parts of base sub-objects providing the constructor has fully run. It is undefined behaviour to use foo() as a parameter for B as A's constructor has not fully run. If it was struct C : A, B it would be defined.

Comment: @SJHowe but the standard explicitely contains the example (at least the latest freely available working draft of C++14, which I just looked on). See https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard the "November 2014 working draft" 12.6.2.16 - if the standard example is right, you are wrong.

Comment: @SJHowe : I don't know why the standard treats that use case as undefined, but according to my reading of it, it does. It seems intuitive that accessing `A::a` after it has been initialized (as is the case when you change it to `struct C : A, B`) should be well-defined. But it seems it's not. So either this is an oversight (or probably more likely - a simplification), or there is a reason for this that I can't see. Either way, it's probably safest not to rely on any kind of behavior re. this.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I would say it is an oversight, brought on by focusing on the virtual case; see [CWG2056](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2056).

Answer (score 5):

This is just another case of undefined behavior. For example, my system gives the following results.

```
B
A
-858993460
Bye A
Bye B
```

Try this [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcaf677e5fb96e71) which produces yet another distinct result (`C(10).bar()` produced 32764).

`foo()` can be called in this context, but it will be called *before* `A`'s constructor. This means `a` is initialized, which leads to reading an uninitialized variable, which leads to undefined behavior. This is similar to accessing a member before it's initialized. Consider the following example. `a` is initialized to `b`'s value, then `b` is initialized. The problem is obvious, `b` is uninitialized at the point where it's read to initialize `a`.

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int x) : a(b), b(x) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    foo bar(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see what was actually happening.  Since I have the results, here they are for you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*** Structures ***/
struct A{
    int a;
#warning a integer declared in struct A

    A(int i=0) : a(i)
#warning A constuctor declared
#warning A constructor creates variable i, sets it to 0
#warning then assigns i to a
    {
        cout << "inside constructor A" << endl;
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        cout << "a = " << a << endl;
        cout << "leaving constructor A" << endl;
    }
#warning A constructor definition provided
    ~A()
#warning A destructor declared
    {
        cout << "inside destructor A" << endl;
        cout << "leaving destructor A" << endl;
    }
#warning A destructor definition provided
    int foo()
#warning foo function declared in struct A
    {
        cout << "inside foo, inside A" << endl;
        cout << "foo will return a = " << a << " then leave foo" << endl;
        return a;
    }
#warning foo function defined in struct A
};

struct B{
    int b;
#warning b integer declared in struct B
    B(int i=0) : b(i)
#warning B constructor declared
#warning B creates int i and initializes it to 0
#warning b is assigned the value of i                 
    {
        cout << "inside constructor B" << endl;
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        cout << "b = " << b << endl;
        cout << "leaving constructor B" << endl;
    }
#warning B constructor defined
    ~B()
#warning B destructor declared
    {
        cout << "inside destructor B" << endl;
        cout << "leaving destructor B" << endl;
    }
#warning B destructor defined    
    int bar()
#warning bar function declared in struct B
    {
        cout << "inside bar, inside B" << endl;
        cout << "bar will return b = " << b << " then leave bar" << endl;
        return b;
    }
#warning bar function defined in struct B
};


struct C : B, A 
#warning C structure declared derived from B and A
{
    C(int i=0) : B(foo()), A(i) 
#warning C constructor declared
#warning C constructor creates int i and assigns value 0
#warning C constructor instantiates B and calls foo from A to assign value?
#warning C constructor instantiates A by assigning i to it
    {
        cout << "inside constructor C" << endl;
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        cout << "leaving constructor C" << endl;
    }
#warning C constructor defined with no implementation
};

int main() {
    cout << "command is: print the value of C(10).bar()" << endl;
    cout << C(10).bar() << endl;
#warning initialize C with a value of 10
#warning then call the bar function extended from B

#warning declare struct C blah, initialized with C(12)
    cout << endl << "creating struct blah with definition C(12)" << endl;
    struct C blah = C(12);
    cout << "calling blah.foo" << endl;
    cout << blah.foo() << endl;
    cout << "calling blah.bar" << endl;
    cout << blah.bar() << endl;
#warning  printing and then returning 0
    cout << endl << "Some random output before returning 0" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following during compilation results (cleaned up a little):

```
>make
test.cpp:7:2:  warning: #warning a integer declared in struct A [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:10:2: warning: #warning A constuctor declared [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:11:2: warning: #warning A constructor creates variable i, sets it to 0 [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:12:2: warning: #warning then assigns i to a [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:19:2: warning: #warning A constructor definition provided [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:21:2: warning: #warning A destructor declared [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:26:2: warning: #warning A destructor definition provided [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:28:2: warning: #warning foo function declared in struct A [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:34:2: warning: #warning foo function defined in struct A [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:39:2: warning: #warning b integer declared in struct B [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:41:2: warning: #warning B constructor declared [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:42:2: warning: #warning B creates int i and initializes it to 0 [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:43:2: warning: #warning b is assigned the value of i [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:50:2: warning: #warning B constructor defined [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:52:2: warning: #warning B destructor declared [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:57:2: warning: #warning B destructor defined [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:59:2: warning: #warning bar function declared in struct B [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:65:2: warning: #warning bar function defined in struct B [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:70:2: warning: #warning C structure declared derived from B and A [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:73:2: warning: #warning C constructor declared [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:74:2: warning: #warning C constructor creates int i and assigns value 0 [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:75:2: warning: #warning C constructor instantiates B and calls foo from A to assign value? [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:76:2: warning: #warning C constructor instantiates A by assigning i to it [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:82:2: warning: #warning C constructor defined with no implementation [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:88:2: warning: #warning initialize C with a value of 10 [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:89:2: warning: #warning then call the bar function extended from B [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:91:2: warning: #warning declare struct C blah, initialized with C(12) [-Wcpp]
test.cpp:98:2: warning: #warning printing and then returning 0 [-Wcpp]
```

And gives the following output:

```
>test
command is: print the value of C(10).bar()
inside foo, inside A
foo will return a = 4201198 then leave foo
inside constructor B
i = 4201198
b = 4201198
leaving constructor B
inside constructor A
i = 10
a = 10
leaving constructor A
inside constructor C
i = 10
leaving constructor C
inside bar, inside B
bar will return b = 4201198 then leave bar
4201198
inside destructor A
leaving destructor A
inside destructor B
leaving destructor B

creating struct blah with definition C(12)
inside foo, inside A
foo will return a = 4201104 then leave foo
inside constructor B
i = 4201104
b = 4201104
leaving constructor B
inside constructor A
i = 12
a = 12
leaving constructor A
inside constructor C
i = 12
leaving constructor C
calling blah.foo
inside foo, inside A
foo will return a = 12 then leave foo
12
calling blah.bar
inside bar, inside B
bar will return b = 4201104 then leave bar
4201104

Some random output before returning 0
inside destructor A
leaving destructor A
inside destructor B
leaving destructor B
```